# How to remove duplicate entries from array of arrays based on nested value?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays that also contains hash value , and that array has duplicate arrays that I want to remove. There is an example below :

```
[[“John, Doe“, "/manager/consumer/123456?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>123456},  :class=>""}],
[“Jane, smith“, "/manager/consumer/7891011?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>7891011},  :class=>""}],
[“William, Smith”, "/manager/consumer/12131415?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>1211415}, :class=>""}],
[“John, Doe“, "/manager/consumer/123456?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>123456}, :class=>""}]]
```

As we can see there are two arrays that are same(first and last), I would like to remove the duplicate one based on the :id present in the hash inside the array ?

Comment: Which one of each group of "duplicate arrays" do you wish to keep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `uniq` method! (ruby >= 1.9.2)

```
array = [
  ["John, Doe", "/manager/consumer/123456?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>123456},  :class=>""}],
  ["Jane, smith", "/manager/consumer/7891011?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>7891011},  :class=>""}],
  ["William, Smith", "/manager/consumer/12131415?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>1211415}, :class=>""}],
  ["John, Doe", "/manager/consumer/123456?status=1", {:data=>{:id=>123456}, :class=>""}]
]

array.uniq { |_name, _url, hash| hash[:data][:id] }
```

In case of duplicate of an id it will remove all but the first entry, so you need to think about a situation when the id is the same but rest of the data is not.

NOTE: if you for some reason are running on ruby before 1.9.2, then `uniq` will ignore the block. For that reason ActiveSupport had `uniq_by` method (which was removed in version 4.0.2).